# chromedriver with selenium on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I wanted to do some javascript integration tests for my app (I use Chrome as a browser) but Capybara is not detecting the Selenium driver.

Here is my test suite:
Linux (Ubuntu 12.10)
RoR 3.1
Rspec
Capybara

I also installed database_cleaner and followed the instructions on how to update my spec_helper and environment:

```
spec_helper

     #Database_cleaner
      config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
      config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
      config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }

      Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
        Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
      end
```

I also downloaded the chromedriver, moved it to my user/bin folder and ran the following command to render it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

The message I get from my autotest is the following:

```
Failure/Error: visit root_path
     LoadError:
       Capybara's selenium driver is unable to load `selenium-webdriver`, please install the gem and add `gem 'selenium-webdriver'` to your Gemfile if you are using bundler.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

as error message, says:

add following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

and run from your app root:

```
bundle install
```